# What do prefixes (#) and (@) signify in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, syntax, 8051

What do prefixes (#) and (@) signify in assembly language?

I assume they may represent data versus address pointer??

Usage examples:

```
mov a, #6
mov @R0, a
```

Thank you in advance for helping clarify this!

Comment: What language are you using, MASM?

Comment: It depends. There isn't just one assembly language, they're all different, *especially* in details such as this.

Comment: Atmel with 8051 Architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See page 12 of [this manual](http://www.xess.com/static/media/manuals/asm51.pdf).

Number sign (#) stands for immediate and @ for indirect addressing.

Comment: Ah, that is the manual I need and could not find.  I am very appreciative of your help.  Thank you!